# tensorflow: how to calculate the zero-mean and of the rgb values and uni-variance

Tags: tensorflow

I want to calculate the zero mean and univariance of an image.

I have already read in a pair of images in a list as tensors with the dimensions (m, n, 3)

The zero-mean is calculated by taking the mean of all red, green, blue values of all images in the list and substract the per image.

For this task, can I use the moments method? if yes, which axes are correct?

```
mean, var = tf.nn.moments(input, axes=[0,1,2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting `mean` and `variance` using `tf.nn.moments` is the right thing. The axes parameter tells which axes to be included fro aggregating.

If you want a single mean\var for the entire `RGB` you can use:

```
 mean, var = tf.nn.moments(RGB, axes=[0,1,2])
```

if you want to get a mean/var for each of the channels(R,G,B), you can use:

```
 mean, var = tf.nn.moments(RGB, axes=[0,1])
```